# error parsing json in asp.net mvc login project

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc

i am fetching data from an asp.net webapi and storing it as

```
var token = string.Empty;
var result = resMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(result);
```

value of result is

```
{
value: "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIiwibmJmIjoxNjMzODY1NzE0LCJleHAiOjE2MzM4Njc1MTQsImlhdCI6MTYzMzg2NTcxNH0.2Vje7sXWw4tb_h50cR3zdI5TDIjOiWR-94_i2mH40cg",
formatters: [ ],
contentTypes: [ ],
declaredType: null,
statusCode: 200
}
```

the error i am getting

```
JsonReaderException: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: {. Path '', line 1, position 1.
```

in this line

```
token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(result);
```

i am not able to understand what is going on. i have written this code in asp.net mvc project

Comment: you json is invalid, what if you try simply `var token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result)`?

Comment: yes it is working @viveknuna

Comment: Good, do you need more help?

Comment: no thanks @viveknuna

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You're trying to deserialise a `string` into a `string` here, which won't work as they're the exact same type.**

You need to deserialise `string result` into a concrete type, which `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` should be aware of, to deserialise it as such.

This should work:

```
public class Data
{
    public string value { get; set; }
    public List<object> formatters { get; set; }
    public List<object> contentTypes { get; set; }
    public object declaredType { get; set; }
    public int statusCode { get; set; }
}
```

```
Data token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Data>(result);
```